# Install Direct X silently via WebInstaller in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, .net-2.0, directx, inno-setup, direct3d

I'd like to install Direct X with a **web-installer** (to make my setup smaller) on a users machine using **Inno Setup** during the setup of my windows application. If possible, I'd like to do that **conditionally**, if Direct X is not installed. If also possible, I'd like to do that **silently**.

I couldn't find out a working way to do this so far - Microsoft seems to make this a bit hard. Can anyone point me into the right direction or describe how this is possible?

EDIT: A semi-working solution can be found here: http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=DirectX_-_How_to_detect_DirectX_version

FYI: After all, I just used the directxwebsetup.exe with the silent flag ("/Q"). When DirectX is installed, just a small GUI flashup is seen, and otherwise a DirectX install GUI opens and installs DX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good sample for detecting the .NET version on the [ISXKB wiki](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=.NET_-_Detect_framework). This can be expanded to use Nick Sherlock's InnoTools downloader to download it and you can then run it with the appropriate command line options to do it silently.

Comment: I needed a way to scan fir the Direct X version and not .NET, but I found another page that helped me in the Wiki you linked : http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=DirectX_-_How_to_detect_DirectX_version

Comment: Ah, sorry, I think there was a DirectX article too.